# PowerApps form doesn't save external data to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I've created custom form with PowerApps so when you click on New button in SharePoint you will see this:

[image]

This form is for SharePoint list ***Workflow*** but for column *CostCenter* I'm using external list ***Companies and Cost Centers*** where I'm filtering values based on selected *Company* (Cascading Dropdown).

I'm able to select data in those two fields correctly but when I hit the Save button in the form the value of *CostCenter* is not saved to ***Workflow*** list but everything else is.

So *Title*, *Property Manager*, *Company*, etc. except *CostCenter* is saved. I guess it's connected to that Data Source of each field but I don't know how to send those data from *CostCenter* to ***Workflow*** too.

[image]
[image]

Thank you for your help.